# JS - Resizing an Iframe based on it's content, without using timeout

Tags: javascript, events, dom, iframe, postmessage

I have an Iframe that communicate with it's parent (on other domain) using window.postMessage.
on the parent window I have a resize method that can be called from the iframe.

I want to add code to the Iframe that will watch for a content dimension change and will call the resize method when needed, I rather not use timeout ... is there an "event way" to do it? 
[image]

**Update**
I use pure JS, and would like to monitor the scroll width and height of the inner document

Comment: Do you have access to the source of the page loading inside the frame to add JS to it?

Comment: I have access for both iframe and the parent window

Comment: What is it that causes the iframe to change sizes? Images loading? Content changing? Normally you would just bind listeners to each of those events.

Comment: Basically it could be any of the above, I've heard about mutation events, but could not figure out if I could use it for my solution

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could trigger an event in the parent window:

```
parent.$("iframe").trigger("resize");
```

And in the parent window you would listen to this event:

```
$("iframe").on("resize", function(){
  // do the magic
});
```

Comment: `parent.$` will not work if two frames are on a different domain due to cross-domain security restrictions.

Comment: the calling to the method is not the issue, the question is how do I know when the content has changed, without using an interval to check it

Answer (score 0):

Like italo.nascimento said, do it with jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var winW = $(this).width(),
        winH = $(this).height();
    $("iframe").css({
        width: winW,
        height: winH
    });
}).resize();
```

Comment: But he wants to resize based on the iframe content. So the iframe itself should tell the main page when to resize the `<iframe>` DOM element.

Comment: @italo.nascimento you are exactly right, the question is when to tell the main page to resize